# Compositing Operations in CARTO VL

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-vl

Is there any way to do (or emulate) the [compositing operations](https://carto.com/help/tutorials/cartocss-compositing-operations/#alpha-composite-operations) that can be done in CartoCSS with CARTO VL? The closest I've been able to find (which hasn't been that close) is the ways to change the colour ramp and opacity, but I'm yet to work out a way to overlay/multiply/screen/etc the colours from two different layers in CARTO VL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to generate composing operations in CARTO VL.